# How to check the content size of a Duplicity backup-set?

Tags: backup, duplicity

Short of restoring to a temp directory, how do I list the content of a Duplicity backup-set *with retained size*?

I want to find out what's caused it to swell but a complex existing set of *excludes* means just looking at the backup source location isn't really practical any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible without restoring; size is not kept as metadata currently.

Comment: Tsk. Why on Earth not? It seems quite a reasonable expectation for a largely opaque backup file